# How to prepare "user task" table for usability testing?

Tags: usability-testing, users, usability-engineering

Nancy J. Wahl's article: [student-run usability testing](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=794319) mentioned 8 steps for preparation of usability testing. Not to forget that he adopted them from Branghan's website.

The third step is to identify "user task" which was suggested to be prepared in a from of a table.

I'm running usability testing in my thesis. All I want is to find a sample of "user task" table to figure out how to import it in my research. It would be much much better if you can suggest an article with sample of all steps, but the most important one that I'm stuck in, is the "user task".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The samples of user task table ([from Tasks and Scenarios section of the page](http://zing.ncsl.nist.gov/iusr/formative/IUSR_Formative/index.html)):
[image]

.

[image]

User tasks in a usability test are wrapped into scenarios, which contain more real-life setups. It's necessary as the participants work with system first time and need to understand the tasks. So you give them scenario (a little story) instead of user task (element of a system specification).

[The article](http://www.usabilitybok.org/task-analysis) describes Task Analysis method very good, but at the stage of usability testing the user tasks should be already defined.

Comment: Thanks man, your answer was what I wanted.
Anyway, check these two links, http://agict.gov.au/files/2012/04/User-Profiling-and-Testing-Toolkit.pdf (page 68) and http://www.paperprototyping.com/downloads/Ch6_task_template.pdf.
These are just some other ways to prepare the task table, do you have any suggestion on which one is the best one?

Comment: @Shawn there is not a standard for task description, it could be brief or more detailed. But you could notice the core elements of it: name, goal, inputs (an instruction to a user), steps to accomplish. Choose any format that suit your needs. Personally I like the second link more as it is more descriptive. Also check [this useful document](http://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/resources/templates/usability-study-process-and-materials-checklist.html).